# LINQ C# - How to show more then 24 hours using timespan

Tags: c#, linq

I have this line in code :

```
TalkTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes((int)g.Sum(b => b.Field<int?>("talkTime"))).ToString("hh':'mm':'ss")
```

I need to show the time as total hours. using totalHours gives me for example 54.33 . I need it to be 54:33:00 ..

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3):

**54:33:00 != 54 hours, twenty minutes and zero seconds**

I think your logic may be off as far as what you are intending to output as [`TimeSpan.TotalHours`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours(v=vs.110).aspx) is going to output a double and not actually the proper number of minutes.

```
// Get your timespan (using the same number of minutes as expected)
var timespan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3260);
// This would output a double and not a string
timespan.TotalMinutes; // yields 55.3333 (i.e. 54 hours and 1/3 or 20 minutes)
```

So I don't believe that you would actually want to output `54:33:00` as that would not be correct as it would mean 54 hours and 33 minutes as opposed to the correct value of 54 hours and 20 minutes, which you can do through the [`String.Format()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) method :

```
// This would output 54:20:00, which should be your correct answer
String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}",(int)timespan.TotalHours, timespan.Minutes,0)
```

So an example of your original code might look like :

```
var talktime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes((int)g.Sum(b => b.Field<int?>("talkTime")));
// Use your talktime to set your proper string variable
TalkTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}",(int)talktime.TotalHours, talktime.Minutes,0);
```

You can [see a working example of this in action here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lwZVVh).

Comment: To avoid *rounding up* for `timespan.TotalHour` (`205.75 -> 206`), please convert it to `int`: `String.Format("...", (int) timespan.TotalHours, ...);`

Comment: Nice Catch Dmitry, I've made the addition accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

`TimeSpan.TotalHours` returns the current time in the `TimeSpan` instance in terms of hours. So the 0.33 is 0.33 of an hour, not 33 minutes. Using math and custom format you can achieve what you are trying to do. Here is an example:

```
    var time = new TimeSpan(54, 21, 0);
    var hours = System.Math.Floor(time.TotalHours);
    var minutes = System.Math.Ceiling((time.TotalHours - hours) * 60); // you can also use time.Minutes
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", hours, minutes, 0));
```

This takes the `Floor` of the `TotalHours` property to determine the hour component and calculates the minutes component by multiplying the fraction of the `TotalHours` property by 60. You can also use `time.Minutes` for the minutes component.

Comment: Ok . I change the code but getting error . How do I implement it in my linq code :
                                  hours = TimeSpan.FromSeconds((int)g.Sum(b => b.Field<int?>("talkTime"))).TotalHours,
                                  minutes = TimeSpan.FromSeconds((int)g.Sum(b => b.Field<int?>("talkTime"))).TotalMinutes,
                                  seconeds = TimeSpan.FromSeconds((int)g.Sum(b => b.Field<int?>("talkTime"))).TotalSeconds,

                                  TalkTime = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", hours, minutes, seconeds),

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the `Total` properties. It seems you think that `TotalHours` will contain the hour component, `TotalMinutes` will contain the minute component. This is not true, these properties hold the total time in terms of the property's unit. For example, if your `TimeSpan` returns 2 for `TotalHours`, that means it will return 120 for `TotalMinutes` and 7200 for `TotalSeconds`. Therefore, if the properties were to be converted into the same unit (such as Milliseconds or Ticks), then they will yield the same result.

Comment: Try this:
            var time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds((int)g.Sum(b => b.Field<int?>("talkTime")));
            var hours = System.Math.Floor(time.TotalHours);
            var minutes = System.Math.Ceiling((time.TotalHours - hours) * 60);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", hours, minutes, 0));

Answer (score 0):

A value for TotalHours of 54.33 doesn't mean 54 hours and 33 minutes, it means 54 hours + 33/100 hour, which 54 hours and 33*60/100 minutes, which is 54 hours and 19.8 minute, or 54 hours, 19 minutes + 0.8*60 seconds = 48 seconds. So 54.33 hours is 54:19:48.

Assuming you want to display a value of decimal 54.33 into a string 54:19:48, I guess the best way is to create a class that implements both IFormatProvice and ICustomFormater. The ICustomFormatter.Format function will do the formatting for you the same way as described above:

- Take the total hours and use Math.Floor to round down to a number of hours.
- Use CultureInfo.DateTimeFormatInfo to investigate whether to add a semicolon or a forward slash, or whatever strange character
- Use the remainder * 60 to calculate the (decimal) number of minutes
- again: Math.Floor to calculate the number of full minutes and remainder to get the number of second
- Do the same to get the number of seconds and number of milliseconds.

[MSDN about IFormatProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) with an example of what to do in ICustomFormatter.Format